# Why Serialize fails to do its job?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serialization, javascriptserializer

I have a simple model for testing:

```
[Serializable]
public class PageModel : IPageModel
    {
        Guid _guid;

        public Guid GUID
        {
            get
            {
                if (_guid == Guid.Empty)
                    _guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                return _guid;
            }
            set
            {
                _guid = value;
            }
        }
        public bool ShouldSerializeGUID()
        {
            return false; // GUID still serialized!
        }
}
```

I try to serialize it like this:

```
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    string jsonData= serializer.Serialize(pageModelInstance);
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Is there another way to do conditional serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `JavaScriptSerializer` doesn't support that pattern of conditional serialization. So: use one that does - fortunately, [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) *does* support this, and works fine:

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pageModelInstance);
```

(no other changes needed, although you can safely remove the `[Serializable]` - that isn't needed)